# D3.js Scale Tick Marks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Am trying to create a time-scale in D3.js. I have the following code

```
time_scale = d3.time.scale()
        .range([0, chart_dimensions.width])
        .domain([d3.min(total_data, function(d) {return new Date('01/07/'+d.year)}),
                    d3.max(total_data, function(d) {return new Date('01/07/'+d.year)})]);

var time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(time_scale);
```

My yearly dates range from `Fri Jan 07 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time` (the output I get when I run the function `time_scale.invert(0)`) to `Tue Jan 07 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (South Africa Standard Time)`, basically 15 dates one per year. The axis draws, however its skips a year when drawing the ticks i.e 2002,2004,2006,2008,2010,2012,2014... when I would prefer either 2001,2002,2003,2004... or 2002, 2004, 2006... but with tick marks between the years indicating the year in between. How can this be achieved in D3.js?

Thanks in advance,
Tumaini

Comment: The only sure way to do this is to set the tick marks explicitly through `.tickValues()` on the axis.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried `var time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(time_scale)
            .tickValues([2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014]);` and this gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` when `call(time_axis)` is called. Also tried with the years in quotes, same error. Is it my syntax? Thanks again

Comment: You need `Date` objects for that, like you're using for the scale.

Comment: OK so now I tried
    `var time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(time_scale)
            .tickValues([new Date('07/01'+'2001'),new Date('07/01'+'2002'),new Date('07/01'+'2003'),new Date('07/01'+'2004'),new Date('07/01'+'2005'),new Date('07/01'+'2006'),new Date('07/01'+'2007'),new Date('07/01'+'2008'),new Date('07/01'+'2009'),new Date('07/01'+'2010'),new Date('07/01'+'2011'),new Date('07/01'+'2012'),new Date('07/01'+'2013'),new Date('07/01/'+'2014')]);`

Still I get `NaN` as the only tick label on my x axis :-(

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Yes, thats possible, it is however 360 lines long, should I just paste it? Thanks

Comment: Ideally a jsfiddle or something like that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=c3SmSmOUU7  line 231 am not sure how to add my data file though...

Comment: You could add it as a static variable.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Tumaini/8jvqk8Ly/ the problem area (tickValues) starts on line 3473. If I remove the specific line for tickValue and leave it as `var time_axis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(time_scale)` it works fine, but with tick values of even numbered years...

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working for me.

Comment: sorry, new to JFiddle, forgot to add the D3.js library, please try again

Comment: You have to update it and will get a new URL.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Tumaini/8jvqk8Ly/2/

Comment: Hmm, not sure why that's not working, but you can also use the convenience function `time_scale.ticks(d3.time.year, 1)`: http://jsfiddle.net/8jvqk8Ly/4/

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect! Not sure how to set this as answered...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sure way of doing this is to use the [`.tickValues()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickValues) and set the tick positions explicitly. As you have a time scale, you can use the convenience function `time_scale.ticks(d3.time.year, 1)` to give you ticks for each year in your domain and pass that to `.tickValues()`.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8jvqk8Ly/4/).